# How to remove first 3 character

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file with following data:

```
KP_site1
KP_site2
KP_site3
```

I want following output:

```
site1
site2
site3
```

How can I achieve this in perl regex?

Comment: Do you want to remove the first 3 characters or do you want to remove the specific `KP_` prefix. There is a difference.

Comment: you can use substring method for that.

Comment: [**@ALL HIGH REPS** CLOSE THIS QUESTION AND STOP REPFARMING](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: @HamZa No need to shout … the question is only half an hour old, and it takes a bit of time for the close votes to trickle in.

Comment: @amon It's sad to see 3 highrep users answer this instead of closevoting it.

Answer (score 4):

For example see the below one with Regex

```
my $str = "1234567890\n";
$str =~ s/^.{$n}//s;
# was: $str =~ s/^.{$n}(.*)$/$1/s;
print $str;
```

without regex

```
    my $n    = 3;

my $str1 = "1234567890\n";
my $str2 = substr($str1, $n);

print $str1; # 1234567890
print $str2; # 4567890
```

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -pi.bak -e's/...//' yourfile
```

Will remove the first three characters on every new line, or none if there are not three characters. It will alter your file and keep a backup with the extension `.bak`.

You can also use `substr` to great effect here, plus it is somewhat intuitive to use.

```
$_ = substr($_, 3);    # returns the string after offset 3
substr($_, 0, 3) = ""; # deletes the substring in offset 0-3
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy with the `=~` operator:

```
$_ =~ s/^KP_//;
```

Customize according to whatever variable you're actually using. This is an in-place modification.

To process an array:

```
map { $_ =~ s/KP_//; $_ } @array;
```

To do this on a file:

```
perl -p -e 's/KP_//' < filename.txt
```